# Map Tips - Omitt field with no data

Tags: qgis, html, hyperlink, css, maptips

I'm using QGIS 2.18.14 and I have currently got a map tip in a shapefile of freehold land titles that looks like this:

[image]

Both, the title plan and register for the land title have been referenced to a hyperlink on dropbox.

The attribute table for the shapefile is below:
[image]

My CSS / HTML for the map tip looks like the following:

```
<style> 
body {
margin-top:0px!important;
white-space: nowrap!important;
}
h1 { 
color: #00713d; 
font-size: 20px; 
font-family: helvetica; 
text-decoration: underline; 
text-align: center; 

} 
h3 { 
color: black; 
font-size: 14px; 
text-decoration: underline; 
font-family: helvetica; 
text-align: center; 
line-height:0px; 
} 
p { 
color:black; 
font-size: 12px; 
font-family: helvetica; 
text-align: center; 
line-height:0px; 
} 
</style> 

<h1> [% "Title No" %] </h1> 
<h3>Proprietor</h3> <p> [%"Proprietor"%]</p> 
<h3> Area</h3> <p> [%"Ac" || ' Ac'%] </p>
<h3> Title Plan</h3> <p><a href=[% "Title Plan"%]>Click Me</a></p> 
<h3> Register</h3> <p><a href=[% "Register" %]>Click Me</a></p>
```

You will notice I have not got a link to the title plan ending '11'. I will be uploading this QGIS project to QGIS Cloud and want to make it as professional looking as possible. How would I go about omitting the row "Title Plan" in the map tip represented below when the entry = 'NULL'?

```
<h3> Title Plan</h3> <p><a href=[% "Title Plan"%]>Click Me</a></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a case statement:

```
<h3> Title Plan</h3> <p>[% case when "Title Plan" is not NULL then '<a href='||"Title Plan"||'>' else '' end case %][% case when "Title Plan" is not NULL then 'Click Me</a>' else 'No title plan available' end case %]</p>
```

If your data is not actually NULL, and just a blank field, you may have to change it to:

```
"Title Plan" != ''
```

Comment: Looks like the ideal solution to me. I will have to test it tomorrow. Thanks for the contribution.